# What is the best way to implement wamp client in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, wamp

I am planing to recreate my Android app on Flutter. I am using in my app Jawampa package. As far as i see, for flutter there isn't as great packages already maid. What is best option, to implement Wamp Client on Flutter, which works both for Android and IOS.
I am looking for solution, which supports Progressive calls, authid change and reconnect. 
Do i need to create custom plugin myself or there already is good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, [connectanum](https://github.com/konsultaner/connectanum-dart) is your best choice because it has all the features that you said. If you want a feature that is not in the package, you can send a pull request because it’s open-source.

Comment: Hi. Is it better than https://github.com/kkazuo/dart-wamp-client?

Comment: I think that the documentation of connectanum it’s better than the one that you are saying.

Comment: I'm the author of connectanum. It has a lot more features then the kkazuo implementation. That was the reason why I started the project.